# Hadoop append data to hdfs file and ignore duplicate entries

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, hive, hdfs

How can I append data to HDFS files and ignore duplicate values?

I have a huge HDFS file (MainFile) and I have 2 other new files from different sources and I want to append data from this files to the MainFile.

Main File and the other files has same structure.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Since HDFS is used for Write Once , Read Many times. we can not change contain of Hdfs file. You are trying to append data to file which is there in hdfs. copy your file intohdfs and then you can use -getmerge utility.

**hadoop fs -getmerge   [addnl].**

One other solution using map reduce is : Take your new file as distrubuted cache file (it should be fit into memory) and read file which is already there in hdfs and compare records in Map method.

Comment: Thanks, is there any solution using hive to prevent duplicate key values , in my case I have ( Key1,Key2, .. , value 1 , value 2 ,.... value n ) each line, what if I create an external _Hive_ table with the main file and append new sources to the _Hive_ table..

Comment: If you append Data into hive table then it will not remove the duplicates. it will just append it to your hive table.

Comment: Look , I have a main file with this structure ( Key1,Key2, .. , value 1 , value 2 ,.... value n ) 
and second file extracted from extern source
and another file extracted from my RDBMS database 
All files with same structure , and i want to append only unique data to the main file and remove old value of each duplicate key and keep the newest.

Comment: Take All three file as input to mapreduce program , in mapper , insert your key as Row key of HBASE table and every time compare it with HBase row key first then if it matches then it exists, if does not match then its new one key.

Answer (score 0):

you can wirte a mapreduce job to merge your files in the hdfs, or you use the read the "2other files" and write to the "MainFile":

```
FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(new Configuration());
FileStatus[] status = fs.listStatus(new Path(/*2 other files*/));
for (int i=0;i<status.length;i++){
    BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fs.open(status[i].getPath())));
    String line;
    line=br.readLine();
    while (line != null){
        line=br.readLine();
        BufferedWriter br=new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(fs.append(/*main file*/));
        br.write(line);
        br.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, But what's the main idea to merge files with mapreduce ? I didn't found a solution to merge files.

Comment: i think you must read all files in the mapper and build a new file in the reducer